# Further/farther into the cave

Tags: adverbs, word-difference

A little misunderstanding here, often when I read books i meet the word "**further**" and not "**farther**" in sentences like:

- He ventured **further into** the cave
- She drove **further away** from town

I've read that **farther** refers *to physical distances* while **further** refers *to figurative and non-physical distances*.

> Sources also say that "*Many counterexamples could be found, however, and using **further** in place of **farther** is never an error.*"

Here's a *Quick Usage Trick* I met in [YourDictionary.Grammar](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/style-and-usage/further-vs-farther.html):

> "If you can't replace "**further**" with "**additional**" in a sentence, you are using it incorrectly."

The Google Ngram shows that "**farther**" is very rarely used:
[image: Ngram]

So "**farther**" is really not in much use nowadays? We can use "**further**" in place of "**farther**" almost everywhere right?

Comment: See the "usage note" here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/farther

Comment: @SteveES Thank you, I know the definitions and the usage. I'm interesting in its appearance in modern English and its complete interchangeability with "**further**" in context of physical distance"

Comment: That's what the usage note says! _"Although some usage guides insist that only farther should be used for physical distance ( We walked farther than we planned), farther and further have been used interchangeably throughout much of their histories. However, only further is used in the adverbial sense “moreover” ( Further, you hurt my feelings) and in the adjectival senses “more extended” ( no further comment) and “additional” ( Further bulletins came in)."_

Answer (score 3):

Straight from the [OxfordDictionaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825133317/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/farther-or-further). I could not find any better source for that.

> She moved further down the train. 
> She moved farther down the train.

Both words share the same roots: in the sentences given above, where the sense is ‘at, to, or by a greater distance’, there is no difference in meaning, and both are equally correct. Further is a much more common word, though, and is additionally used in various abstract and metaphorical contexts, for example referring to time, in which farther is unusual, e.g.:

> without further delay 
>  Have you anything further to say? 
> We intend to stay a further two weeks.

The same distinction is made between farthest and furthest, e.g.:

> the farthest point from the sun 
> The first team has gone furthest in its analysis.

Comment: See my comment to SteveES